# The plpearsonIII function should return a zero-length vector when input has length zero

Tags: r

I'm using the following expression:

```
fitlpIII <- fitdist(log(Data), dlpearsonIII, start=list(meanlog=mean(log(Data)), sdlog=sd(log(Data)), skew=e1071::skewness(log(Data), type= 1)))
```

But it is showing the following error:

> Warning message: In fitdist(log(Dados), dlpearsonIII, start =
> list(meanlog = mean(log(Dados)),  :   The plpearsonIII function should
> return a zero-length vector when input has length zero

Comment: Could you share your data?

Comment: Yes. 
Data <- c(38.8,40.0,44.1,44.4,58.6,60.5,62.4,65.4,66.6,67.3,68.3,70.0,70.0,70.4,77.1,77.4,78.4,86.9,94.9,95.1,98.0,107.9,126.6);

Comment: Got a different error, but it seems related to the `optim` function, so I guess the start parameters are the problem. Will try somenthing different

Comment: Could you provide your email?

Answer (score 0):

From what I saw, your data has a different density from the function, so the it is giving an error, since it can find the estimated values from your start values.

Here I calculated the metrics from the original data and then simulated data with then from the distribution.

### Libraries

```
# remotes::install_github("USGS-R/smwrBase")
library(smwrBase)
library(tidyverse)
```

### Example Data

```
x <- c(38.8,40.0,44.1,44.4,58.6,60.5,62.4,65.4,66.6,67.3,68.3,70.0,70.0,70.4,77.1,77.4,78.4,86.9,94.9,95.1,98.0,107.9,126.6)
```

### Calculated metrics

```
lx <- log(x)
sd_log <- sd(lx)
mean_log <-  mean(lx)
skew_log <- e1071::skewness(lx,type= 1)
```

### Simulated Data from the distribution using original data metrics

```
simul_x <- rlpearsonIII(n = 1000,sdlog = sd_log,meanlog =mean_log,skew = slew_log)
```

#### Plot Code

```
tibble(
  value = c(lx,simul_x),
  name = c(rep("Original",length(lx)),rep("Simulated",length(simul_x)))) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(value,col = name))+
  geom_density()+
  facet_wrap(~name,scales = "free")
```

[image]

Comment: In case my data doesn't work for this distribution?